# Experimental python tcp-proxy not working

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I just tried to implement a python app that acts like a proxy (for port 22)
The code is as following:

```
import socket
import select
import code
inputSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
inputSock.bind( ('',9999) )
inputSock.listen(5)
socks = {} #a dictionary!

#Now, wait for an input!
while 1:
    #accept new conns
    (sread,swrite,sexec) = select.select([inputSock],[],[])
    for sock in sread:
        print("Got an input!")
        newsock,(remhost,remport) = sock.accept()
        sendsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            print("Now connecting to the centOS...")
            sendsock.connect( ('202.131.30.12',80))
        except:
            print("ERROR: cannot connect to host 192.168.52.128:22")
        print("successfully connected to Cent. Creating new socks")
        socks[id(sendsock)] = newsock
        socks[id(newsock)] = sendsock
        print("socks created!")
    #recv from socks, etc.
    (sread,swrite,sexec) = select.select(socks.values(),[],[])
    for sock in sread:
        print("got input!")
        data = sock.recv(700)
        print(data)
        if(data == ""):
            #remove that sock.
            id1 = id(sock)
            id2 = id(socks[id1])
            socks.pop(id1)
            socks.pop(id2)
            print("removed empty conns")
        else:
            #code.interact(globals=globals())
            sendSock = socks[id(sock)]
            sendSock.send(data)
            print("data sent!")
```

Now, when I run the script, and point my browser to 127.0.0.1:9999, my browser won't get the web page (in some 'forever loading the webpage' state). And this is what I get from the python prompt:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsHud.jpg

Could you help me find where I got wrong & fix this experimental implementation?
(Or give me some links to get an idea?)
Thanks :)

Comment: Please copy the output text to your post; a screenshot is next to useless.

Comment: Also, you seem to have forgotten to include an actual *problem* in your question. What is wrong? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: ok @MartijnPieters - I  guess I should manually type the output :(

Comment: See http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/ how to copy to the clipboard from the console.

Comment: thanks! I guess I'll just copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

You've read some (might be partial) data of HTTP request from the browser and sent it to the server on the other socket. Then the outer loop brought you back to `select` on the listening socket, which blocks waiting for new connections, so you're stuck.

Merge both calls to `select` into one. Just make a special case for the listening socket.